# Load Testing of web application with SSL based authentication using HP Loadrunner

Tags: ssl-certificate, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I'm pretty new in performance testing. I have an application that uses SSL authentication for user login. The requirement is to load test the application using 1000 users. I do not have so many certificates available & no way it is possible to add certificates in the system. Is there anyway certificates can be simulated (without having the actual SSL certificates) using HP Loadrunner?

Comment: Do you really need to use *unique* certificates? Perhaps it would be sufficient to use the same certificate for all users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to certificate based authentication where your application communicates via HTTP/SSL.  Correct me if I am incorrect.

If your requirement is to test 1000 unique users signed in via certificates then you will need 1000 unique certificates.  There is nothing LoadRunner or any tool can do to change the physics of your requirement.

Have the certificates generated or descope the test as untestable given the available test data.